# how to print first and last value of one list in another list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print first and last value of list `a` in `b`. I'm a newbie in python

```
b = []
a = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

  for i in a:
        if i == 0:
          b.append(a[i])
         if i == len(a)-1:
           b.append(a[i])
```

**Expected Result**

```
print(b)
[5,25]
```

Comment: `b = [a[0], a[-1]]`

Comment: Note that looping over an iterable yields the values from the iterable, not their indices.  See `for i in a: print(i)`.  You can also get the index with `for i, x in enumerate(a)`

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]

print(a[0])
print(a[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python you don't need to be calculating the length of a list. If you want to add the first and the last elements of a list into another, you only have to do this:

```
a = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]
b = [a[0],a[-1]]
print(b)
```